# $(A\cup B)\cap C$ is disjoint if and only if $A\cup C$ is disjoint and $B\cup C$ is disjoint

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove this for a class. Teacher said that this means for all $x, x$ must appear in either $A\cup B$ or $C$, but not both and told me to start by enumerating the possible sets $x$ can exist in and gave me this:

$$(A\cup B)\cap C = \emptyset \iff$$

$
1.) \forall x, x \in A\cup B \text{ and } x \notin C \\
2.) \forall x, x \in C \text{ and } x \notin A\cup B
$

I believe the only thing left to do with this is show that each possible case means that $A\cap C = \emptyset \text{ and } B\cap C = \emptyset$. Therefore I came up with this:

$
1.) \forall x, x \in A\cup B \text{ and } x \notin C \implies x \in A \text{ or } x \in B \text{ and } x \notin C \implies (x \in A \text { and } x \notin C) \text{ and } (x \in B \text{ and } x \notin C) \implies A\cap C = \emptyset \text{ and } B\cap C = \emptyset \\$

$\\2.) \forall x, x \in C \text{ and } x \notin A\cup B \implies x \in C \text{ and } x \notin A \text{ and } x \notin B \implies (x \in C, x \notin A) \text{ and } (x \in C, x \notin B) \implies A\cap C = \emptyset, B\cap C = \emptyset
$

Is this sufficient? Given what the teacher has already given me I feel like that's the only place I can go?

Comment: The statement as you wrote it is muddled. What do you mean, $\forall x$ $x \in A \cup B$ and $x \notin C$? That will never be true, there are always $x $s that aren't in $A \cup B$.

Comment: @6005: What he wanted to say is $\forall x \in A \cup B: x \notin C$. Just say the stuff out loud, what it means and you will see, that is sufficient (you might want to elaborate single steps when telling your class, saying an element is in $A \cup B$ if and only if it is at least in $A$ or $B$.

Comment: @ctst Right. For some reason I don't like how she started out the proof for me though. I feel like its sloppy to enumerate all possible outcomes, instead of prove it like a regular iff, where I'd assume $a$ then prove $b$, then assume $b$ and prove $a$ Consequently I'm skeptical of the validity of the above proof but idk

Comment: Well, there is actually a mistake in the first part: $x \in A \cup B$ means not $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ but "or" instead of "and". Do you want to show the above iff or do you want to do something else? Also you should really correct your notion into $\forall x \in ...$ instead of the thing you have there.

Comment: @ctst Where is my and/or error? In the first part I don't see it

Comment: And I was only told that if the text in the title of this question is true, I need to prove it

Comment: Well, e.g. consider your set of integral numbers. A=B the set of numbers divisible by 5 respectivly 7 and C the set consisting only of the number 2. Then the number 1 is in neither set.

Answer (score 1):

First you should correct your notion into something like that (also in your proof)

$ (A \cup B) \cap C = \emptyset \iff$
these two conditions hold:

1. $\forall x \in (A \cup B) $ holds $ x \notin C$
2. $\forall x \in C  $ holds $ x \notin A \cup B$

This does **NOT** mean every $x$ is either in $A\cup B$ or $C$ but instead every $x$ is at most in one of those two sets (so in one or in none). There is also a slight mistake in your first implication:

> $1.) x \in A \text{ or } x \in B \text{ and } x \notin C \implies (x \in A \text {
>  and } x \notin C) \text{ and } (x \in B \text{ and } x \notin C)$

should be

> $x \in A \text{ or } x \in B \text{ and } x \notin C \implies (x \in A \text {
>  and } x \notin C) \text{ or } (x \in B \text{ and } x \notin C)$

I am still not quite sure, what exactly you wanted to show (since you can just see $A\cup B=M$ as a set and then it gets quite easy. Maybe you should show this is equivalent to $A \cap C = \emptyset$ and $B \cap C = \emptyset$. You could do this by showing $(A\cup B) \cap C = (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C)$ and then plugging in that the union of two sets is empty if the two sets are already empty or doing your proof (for one direction).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess the only thing I'm trying to show is that the title text in my question is true. I am not sure if a one-way proof is ok for this or not. I think I'm going to do the one way proof as you have it, and I believe doing the other way will be trivial. Showing that if $P\cup Q = \emptyset \implies P = \emptyset \land Q = \emptyset$ is rather easy as you've said

Comment: I'm a bit confused about something. If $x \in A\cup B$ AND $x \notin C$, doesn't that mean both $A\cap C$ AND $B\cap C$ must be disjoint without exception? Yet my implication (once corrected) only shows that either $A\cap C$ OR $B\cap C$ must be disjoint.

Comment: It means both are disjoint. Disjoint means for every $x$ in one set, it is not contained in the other. Now think you have an $x$ contained in $A$ and $C$ (which means $A$ and $C$ are not disjoint) then it is of course contained in $A \cup B$ and $C$. On the other hand if $x$ is contained in $A \cup B$ and $C$ then it has to be already in $A$ or $B$ (or both) and $C$ and hence either ($A$ and $C$) or ($B$ and $C$) are not disjoint.